# setting a videoview above an image in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-videoview

I want to create the following view for an android app .
The view should be relative, when it opens on different screen sizes the videoview should be inside the frames of the image

[image: preview]

and here is the xml file so far :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/updatemsg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/upgradevideo"
        android:layout_width="757dp"
        android:layout_height="426dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upgrade_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this layout?

Comment: on different screen sizes the videoview doesnt appear inside the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a view on another view in xml file, then you have to use FrameLayout.
Use gravity attribute to make the layout supporting all types of screens in android.
Don't use pixels in place of width and height. Always use fill_parent or wrap_content.

See this below code to understand FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#00000c"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Frame Layout Sample"
    android:textColor="#fafafa"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="28/May/2015"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `FrameLayout`, which does not have relational attributes for its children (and here we want to have a view *into* another).

You approach (`LinearLayout` with a background) seems correct to me. All you have to to is find the right paddings for your layout. I would get rid of the `layout_margin` attributes, and just use `android:paddingTop`,`android:paddingStart`,`android:paddingEnd`,`android:paddingBottom` on the parent layout.

As for the consistence with different devices, you can set different dimensions, like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/updatemsg"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top" >
```

Then you just define a `dimen` resource in different folders, so the same attribute will be rendered with different values depending on the screen size/orientation. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Example:
**values/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="padding_top">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Example:
**values-xlarge/dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="padding_top">40dp</dimen>
    <!-- this value will be used for very large devices -->
</resources>
```

I would also suggest you to not hardcode `layout_width` and `layout_heigth` attributes of the `VideoView`. Try having dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout` for this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/upgradevideo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 //make childrens here,they will appear one above the other

</FrameLayout
```